# client.fetch_user() doesnt work when hosted on herokou for me

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

so today i was testing a leaderboard command and it worked for me but after hosting it to herokou it gave me this error:

```
2021-02-07T18:54:24.504724+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2021-02-07T18:54:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2021-02-07T18:54:27.747125+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`

2021-02-07T18:54:28.379755+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up

2021-02-07T18:54:29.527430+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<fstring>", line 1

2021-02-07T18:54:29.527452+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ((await client.fetch_user(str(x[0]))).name)

2021-02-07T18:54:29.527458+00:00 app[worker.1]:                  ^

2021-02-07T18:54:29.527459+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2021-02-07T18:54:29.574256+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-02-07T18:54:29.634600+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

also for cotext here is my code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['top'])
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(f"SELECT id, bal FROM main ORDER BY bal DESC LIMIT 10")
    result = c.fetchall()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboards", colour=discord.Colour(0x6790a7))
    for i, x in enumerate(result, 1):
        embed.add_field(name=f"#{i}", value=f"**{(await client.fetch_user(str(x[0]))).name}** - {str(x[1])}$", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

when i try to run my bot on my pc it works fine, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have all the correct libraries listed in your requirements.txt file for Heroku to download?

Comment: @AdityaTomar do client methods need requirements?

Comment: Well, not clients in particular, but Discord itself. In your `requirements.txt` file, include `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`, `PyNaCl==1.3.0`, `dnspython==1.16.0`, `pandas`, etc., based on all the libraries you need to run your code.

Comment: @AdityaTomar well it worked fine before i added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, it didnt work but i found an alternative method being:

```
@client.command(aliases=['top'])
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(f"SELECT id, bal FROM main ORDER BY bal DESC LIMIT 10")
    result = c.fetchall()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboards", colour=discord.Colour(0x6790a7))
    for i, x in enumerate(result, 1):
        name = (await client.fetch_user(str(x[0]))).name
        embed.add_field(name=f"#{i}", value=f"**{name}** - {str(x[1])}$", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

isntead on putting it in one line of code i added another one, works now